# For SCSI, was there a change to the definition of ADDITIONAL LENGTH?

Tags: scsi

I am reading the SCSI SPC4r22. In regards to ADDITIONAL LENGTH all revisions prior to spc3 have stated the following ("shall not be adjusted"):

### From spc2r20.pdf:

"The ADDITIONAL LENGTH field shall specify the length in bytes of the parameters.  If the ALLOCATION LENGTH of the CDB is too small to transfer all of the parameters, the ADDITIONAL LENGTH shall not be adjusted to reflect the truncation."

But I don't see that statement in SPC3 or SPC4. Has that been changed or am I missing the phrase? If I'm missing it, can someone please quote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just worded in a more general way:

"If the information being transferred to the Data-In Buffer includes fields containing counts of the number of bytes in some or all of the data, then the contents of these fields shall not
be altered to reflect the truncation"